# Calling ST_Transform in geometry that is already in target srid?

Tags: postgis, srid

I'm writing a function that has a geometry as a parameter that can be in different projections:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(in geometry) RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE
    transformed_geom geometry := in;
BEGIN
    IF ST_SRID(transformed_geom) != 32737 THEN
        transformed_geom := ST_Transform(transformed_geom, 32737);
    END IF;
    [ ... ]
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The function needs the geometry in a specific projection (32737) but I don't want to obligate the caller to make the transformation, I prefer to handle it inside the function.

The question is, instead of check the actual srid, it's safe to always call [ST_Transform](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html)? Will do anything if the geometry is already in the target projection?

I check with a query like this that it seems to be safe, but it will be awesome if someone can confirm this as I did not see it in the docs.

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom), ST_AsEWKT(ST_Transform(geom, 32737)) FROM table_in_32737;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function checks for same in and out srid, and returns untouched if so, [as the source code shows](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/trunk/postgis/lwgeom_transform.c#L71):

```
/*
* If input SRID and output SRID are equal, return geometry
* without transform it
*/
if ( input_srid == output_srid )
    PG_RETURN_POINTER(PG_GETARG_DATUM(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for link the source code. That's the unique source of truth.